# Why won't my colab display all columns when printing cpd from pgmpy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

The blow colab workbook is displaying different information for me after I run it than it's showing online. Why? It's cutting of the number of columns shown.

[Learning Bayesian Networks](https://colab.research.google.com/github/kristiyandd/ai-combinator/blob/master/Learning_Bayesian_Networks.ipynb#scrollTo=njSaSDoFkcvK)

What is being shown:
[image]

After I run the code:

[image]

Notice the ... reducing the number of columns shown. How do I fix this?

I have tried:

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to a configuration hard coded in the pgmy's CPD implementation.

Here's how to fix:

1. Navigate to `pgmpy/factors/discrete/CPD.py`
2. Around `Line 231`, you'll find `cdf_str = self._truncate_strtable(cdf_str)`
3. Comment out this line.

It should now be working. There should be a pgmpy-specific config command that should fix this in a better way but I couldn't find one.